# Unwanted section marks in Exercises, Index and Bibliography headings

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer, xindy, section-titles, unnumbered-sections

I am writing a book in `twoside` `book` documentclass. I am using the following code snippet to modify my headers and footers.

```
% Header-Footer
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\renewcommand\cftsecpresnum{\S}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter.\ #1}}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\S\thesection.\ #1}}
```

And here is my `Exercises` environment:

```
\newlist{exercise}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[exercise]{
    label*=\thechapter.\arabic*.,
    ref=\thechapter.\arabic*, 
    before={%
        \section*{\hfil{Exercises -- \thechapter}}%
        \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Exercises -- \thechapter}%
        \setlist*[enumerate,1]{ref=\theexercisei.~\arabic*}%
        \setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}%
    },
}
\setlist*[enumerate,2]{ref=\theenumi.(\alph*)}
```

Here are the issues I am looking solutions for:

1. The section name `Exercises` is not showing up in the header. Insted, the header is continuing with the last section name.[image]
2. The `Bibliography` and the `Index` pages are showing the chapter names in both left and right headers.[image]
   [image] In the `Bibliography` and `Index` chapters, I want to get rid of the chapter names appearing in the sectionname space.

I am a bit confused about what to include in an MWE. If anybody needs one, please ask me about things that might be affecting this and I will include them and post an MWE.

Comment: `\section*` doesn't set the right mark, so add `\markright{...}` with the same text as used for the section heading, right after launching the `\section*` in the `\setlist{exercise}`.  Similarly, when launching the bibliography and index, insert `\markright{ }` in a place that will take effect before the first page of that chapter is complete; this may be just before the `\bibliography` or `\printindex` commands, and it may be necessary to insert `\newpage before the `\markright`.  (not tested)

Comment: Thanks a lot! They worked. Only thing is that I needed to put `\markright{}` after `\bibliography{...}` and \printindex` commands. Why don't you make it an answer so that I can upvote this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many document classes (including the basic `book`), `\section*` doesn't set the right mark, so add `\markright{...}` with the same text as used for the section heading, right after launching the `\section*`. Here, that should be done in the `\setlist{exercise}` definition.

Similarly, when launching the bibliography and index, insert an empty `\markright{}` in a place that will take effect before the first page of that chapter is complete.  The mark command will take effect on the page where it is read in by (La)TeX.

Where the mark is inserted depends on how these starred components (`\chapter*` or `\section*) are defined and used.  Assume that they are launched by`\bibliography`and`\printindex`.  With these commands, the starred command is part of those definitions, and thus will appear in a derived file (`.bbl`or`.ind`) instead of in the main source file.
If such a component is more than one page long, placing the mark command after the component-launching command will delay the inclusion of the mark in the page heading until the page when it is read.

It is inadvisable to make manual changes in a `.bbl` or `.ind` file as those files will be regenerated with the next LaTeX run.  In such a case, the mark command should be inserted just before the component-launching command (`\bibliography` or `\printindex`), preceded by `\newpage` so that the changed heading doesn't appear before it is wanted.